# How to send data from MYSQL/PHP to a Coldfusion component?

Tags: php, mysql, coldfusion

I'm trying to create functionality to output pages generated from MYSQL queries in PHP as PDF files.

To do this I need a way of wrapping up this data that is placed into dynamic tables and placing it between the  tags, so it can be converted into a clean PDF.

I'm not sure where to start with this other than the coldfusion component will be called from the PHP page, rather than the other way round as I originally envisaged.

Comment: See ColdFusion's `cfdocument` tag. [cfdocument documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c21.html). Everything between those tags will be converted to a PDF document.  Not sure where the PHP will come in.  All of this can be done in ColdFusion if you can move the queries over.

Comment: Yeh that's what I'm asking how to pass the data when I call the component.

Comment: but if you call a component then you will also need to deal with returning the generated PDF contents back to PHP.  If ColdFusion is available, why not handle it there?

Comment: I suggest passing the data in a software agnostic format such as xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would pull the dynamic content from your php scripts like this:

```
<CFDOCUMENT format="pdf" src="url-to-php-script.php" mimetype="text/html" filename="#expandpath("your.pdf")#" />
```

Comment: How would i specify this as the filepath?
localhost:81/ipadappquery/caseidtest2.php

Comment: The `src`-attribute only takes an webroot-relative or full url: http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#cfdocument - as far as I can see there is no way to specify a file on hdd from which cfdocument should grab its source content.

Answer (score 1):

The part where the Coldfusion Component gets called by php is pretty simple to accomplish.  Inside the the cfc you will have functions.  If you make the access property = remote, that function will be available as a web service.

```
<cffunction name="NameOfFunction" access="remote" returntype="something">
```