# How to convert content from a MYSQL query in PHP to a PDF document using Coldfusion?

Tags: php, pdf, coldfusion

I need to convert data from a MYSQL database that is rendered into a page using PHP into a PDF document.

Coldfusion is my weapon of choice for converting pages to PDF as the  tags make it easy.

Coldfusion is excuted from its own server and the PHP is executed from an Apache server.

The problem I have is getting the Coldfusion to execute my PHP page so it can be converted into a PDF as it doesn't include PHP support as standard.

Comment: Too broad question IMO. And has nothing to do with MySQL. Isn't your question "How to execute PHP from Coldfusion"?

Comment: I've had good results using the fPDF library for PHP to generate PDF documents from arbitrary data sources. See: http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: well more how to execute PHP from Coldfusion?

Comment: Well I'd suggest to reword the question that way...

Comment: I'd rather not use fPDF because it seems to require code for every aspect for the document.

Comment: If you have both PHP and ColdFusion available to use, you could use ColdFusion to issue an HTTP call to the PHP server using CFHTTP to get the content, which you can then run through ColdFusion's PDF functions. Does it matter where the initial http call (generated from a user's browser I assume) comes from?

Comment: Thanks, no it doesn't matter really. I've tried CFHTTP and its coming back blank.

Comment: If you're having problems with cfhttp, I'd recommend using Fiddler to debug what's happening. Install it, set 'allow remote computers to connect' in settings->Connections,  then add proxyserver="myLocalDevMachine" proxyport="8888" in your cfhttp call and Fiddler will record what CF is requesting. If you compare the request to the working one in your browser, the difference will likely be the problem

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237047/how-to-send-data-from-mysql-php-to-a-coldfusion-component  Perhaps you need to be more specific with your issue, show some code examples of what you are trying to do and let us know what is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered simply using CFHTTP to request the PHP page that renders the SQL data as HTML?  You could then take the resulting HTML and wrap that in `cfdocument` to make your PDF.

Alternatively, from PHP you could use the PDF "service" that's included as a part of CF 9 and later.  Check out the WSDL here: http://{your host name}/CFIDE/services/document.cfc?wsdl

This provides most of the capabilities of cfdocument as a service. [Here's a quick link with some details](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/leveraging-coldfusion-9)